# What's the best way to migrate large amounts of data to another server?

Tags: php, apache, ftp, migration

I'm currently migrating a Magento installation to a new, separate server and I was wondering whether there's any method I could use apart from an FTP program like FileZilla.  The backup size is around 4GB - so this would take hours to download and upload to the new location.

Is there any way of copying/moving files between servers?  I looked at PHP's [FTP functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php), but I'm unsure if this is the right way to go. I tried searching for previous questions, but all I found was Python and C++ solutions which I'm not that comfortable using...

Comment: Yeah I do. An easy solution would be to specify a remote FTP server as the backup destination, but I was interested if there were any other ways of doing it.

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong with moving everything through ftp?
Just login with ssh to the new server and download everything you need.

Comment: I think the OP meant something along the lines of downloading everything to his PC first and then later uploading it by FTP to the second server. Using FTP instead of scp/ssh as mentioned in the other answers would work just as well if you were to do it from one server directly to the second server except for the fact that the transmission is insecure and scp/ssh are greatly preferred if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tar cfz - /path/to/your/data|ssh user@newserver.com echo > oldserver.tar.gz
```

Comment: I agree. Just backup your db and zip up a copy of your entire site. Then download both files and move them to the new server. Then decompress and setup the db again.

Comment: Probably the most sensible solution. My host makes you pay an additional fee for every reseller sub-account that you require SSH access for. How annoying.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, with** `SSH` **and** `scp`

Assuming that you have ssh access (on both servers) and are working on linux machines, you can login to the old server via ssh and then use `scp`:

```
scp /path/to/backup.tar.gz username@new-server.com:/path/on/new/server
```

Comment: Or rsync, I have heard it is popular too.

Answer (score 0):

is posibbly between servers, but you need

tar and if you want, compress it.
you could use native php extensions, or pear extensions.

So you need to uncompres

1. Make a compress file of backup in the source server
2. In the destiny server do a script what writes tar, here could be 2 scenarios.

   - Can connect directly to http `$tar = new Archive_Tar('http://my-old-host.tld/archive.tar');`
   - You need to download first. With curl http://www.webdigity.com/index.php?action=tutorial;code=45 or with pear http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-download.php

   then you unpack with pear Archive_tar (if you add compression, you need to add here too)

   $tar = new Archive_Tar('http://my-old-host.tld/archive.tar'); 
   $tar->extract(dirname(**FILE**).'/backup_from_server/');

The most easy HTTP compatible way that i think.
have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

with ssh is much more simplier

```
tar -jcvf - /backup-directory | ssh user@destiny-server sh -c 'mkdir backup; cd backup; tar -jxvf -'
```

this sent compressed the stream in the network to make it more faster.